# Run Kivy 2.00 on Mac OS Anaconda

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, kivy

I am trying to open and run Kivy 2.00 via Anaconda on Mac OS Big Sur 11.5.2 I ran conda install -c conda-forge kivy and my terminal tells me Kivy is installed. I can look in Anaconda and see that Kivy is there, too.

I just can't find any way to open it and use it. I've also tried downloading the Kivy.app from Kivy.org official site, but my Mac flags it as potential malware and won't allow me to run it.